# How do I make Windows 10 open Google Docs urls with Chrome and all others with Firefox?

Tags: windows-10

My current setup with a very restricted Firefox as the default browser makes for some reason Google Docs freeze when working in Firefox. All works well in Chrome of course. Now, I want to keep Firefox locked down, but at the same time I want a clean experience in Google Docs. I now wonder:

**Can you in any way, without programming, filter by domain which urls are to be opened by Firefox and which ones should be opened by Chrome in Windows 10?**

I am sure I can make Google docs work in Firefox, it is the above functionality I am after.

Comment: How do you open the URLs?

Comment: I click on links in various applications in Windows, and the Default web browser settings come into play I guess.